Modify ClassPath for ResourceDocumentSource
I have a Java 21 Spring Boot 3.3.1 application. It is an MVC app. The application sends out several different GraphQL requests, and I currently have the template files located in:
src
 |- main
     |- resources
            |- graphql-documents
                      |- templates
                      |     |- templateC.graphql
                      |- templateA.graphql
                      |- templateB.graphql

It reads from graphql-documents/ just fine (it is the default directory for HttpSyncGraphQlClient). However, it will not look at any subdirectories. So it is only able to get templateA and templateB, it will not get templateC.
I tried creating my own DocumentSource class to point to subdirectories, but it is not working:
@Configuration
public class HttpConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestClient getRestClient() {
        return RestClient.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSyncGraphQlClient getGraphQlClient(RestClient restClient) {
        return HttpSyncGraphQlClient.builder(restClient).documentSource(new GraphQlDocumentSource()).build();
    }

    private static class GraphQlDocumentSource implements DocumentSource {

        private final ResourceDocumentSource delegate;

        public GraphQlDocumentSource() {
            this.delegate = new ResourceDocumentSource(
                    Collections.singletonList(new ClassPathResource("graphql-documents/**")),
                    ResourceDocumentSource.FILE_EXTENSIONS);
        }

        @Override
        public @NonNull Mono<String> getDocument(@NonNull String name) {
            return delegate.getDocument(name);
        }

    }

}

I have tried combinations of graphql-documents (this is just the default one though), graphql-documents/, graphql-documents/**, graphql-documents/**/* but none of them will look in subdirectories.
How do I get it to search for .graphql files under all directories under the graphql-documents directory?

I think you can achieve this the following way:
@Configuration
public class HttpConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestClient getRestClient() {
        return RestClient.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSyncGraphQlClient getGraphQlClient(RestClient restClient) {
        List<Resource> folders= List.of(new ClassPathResource("graphql-documents/"),
            new ClassPathResource("graphql-documents/templates/"));
        ResourceDocumentSource source = new ResourceDocumentSource(folders, 
            ResourceDocumentSource.FILE_EXTENSIONS);
        return HttpSyncGraphQlClient.builder(restClient).documentSource(source).build();
    }

}

